# Prove that $\mathbb Z(S) = \mathbb Q(S)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Definitions:

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $S$ be a set. We will call field of algebraic fractions or rational functions on $A$ with indeterminates in $S$ to the field of quotients of $A[S]$. We will represent it by $A(S)$.

This is what I have tried:

Since $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$. Then $\mathbb Z[S]\subset \mathbb Q[S]$. And we know that $\mathbb Q[S] \subset \mathbb Q(S)$. So $\mathbb Z[S] \subset \mathbb Q(S)$. Then $\mathbb Z[S] \subset \mathbb Z(S)\subset \mathbb Q(S)$.
Now I have to show $\mathbb Q(S) \subset \mathbb Z (S)$. I have an idea, to prove that I have to show that $Q[S] \subset \mathbb Z(S)$.

**ADDED:**

Each monomial $p$ of $\mathbb Q[S]$ can be expressed as the finite product of certain indeterminates of $S$ with certain exponents  with a coefficient of the form $a/b$ such that $a,b\in \mathbb Z$. Each of these monomials expressed in this way can be bijected with a monomial $p'$of $\mathbb Z(S)$ simply choosing as an image the monomial in whose numerator the indeterminates that appear are the same as $p$ and that the exponents of these indeterminates are also the same with coefficient $a$, and the monomial $b$ appears in the denominator. This bijection between $p$ and $p'$ allows us to form a monomorphism between $Q[S]$ and $Z(S)$. So $\mathbb Q[S] \subset \mathbb Z(S)$, so $Q[S]\subset Q(S)\subset Z(S)$.

Comment: Note that any $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ is unital in $\mathbb{Z}(S)$.

Comment: Any polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ multiplied by a single rational number (think "clearing denominators"). Apply this to the numerator and denominator of the rational function with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$